# Approximate field into a parabola

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

A farmer owns a paddock that is bounded by part of a river and a straight road running east-west as in the diagram below. The part of the river forming the paddock can be regarded as cubic $(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$ in shape. The farmer wishes to divide the paddock into two paddocks of equal area by running a straight fence from point $A$ (the western junction of the river and the road) to point $B$ on the river.

The questions are

a)  Dealing with a cubic can be difficult. Approximate this field to a parabola, find the area of the two paddocks so formed and the length of the fence from $A$ to $B$.

b)  Using a real field (as a cubic) repeat this, find the area of the two paddocks so formed and the length of the fence from $A$ to $B$.

This is math homework. I'm really stuck and have no idea what to do, please help me; thanks.

[Here is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OEbd.png)

Comment: It's all we got but if I had to guess it's (0,0) as the line that is 120 is to show the length but is not the actual y-axis.

Comment: A variant of this problem is discussed [at another website here](https://www.freemathhelp.com/forum/threads/106788-Find-the-line-that-halves-the-area-of-a-cubic-function-y-0-00111111x-3-0-1x-2-120/) - but they did not solve it up to the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a solution for part (b).**

We choose a coordinate system with origin $A(0,0)$ at the lower left corner of the picture. Let $$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx +d.$$
Then $$f'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c. $$

From the given picture we immediately see that $d=0$ because $d$ is the $y$-intercept of the blue cubic curve (the "river").

We can also find $a$, $b$, $c$ from the picture. We simply observe that the cubic curve must go through the points $(30,120)$, $(90,0)$; and the slope $f'(90)$ is zero. This gives us the equations
$$
f(30) = a\cdot30^3 + b\cdot 30^2 + c\cdot 30 = 120 \\
f(90) = a\cdot90^3 + b\cdot 90^2 + c\cdot 90 = 0 \\
f'(90) = 3a\cdot90^2 + 2b\cdot90 + c= 0.
$$
Solving these equations we find 
$a = {1\over900}, \  b = -{1\over5}, \  c = 9. \ $
So our cubic curve is 
$$
f(x)={1\over900}x^3 -{1\over5}x^2 +9x.
$$

The total area of the two paddocks (bounded by the river and the road) is
$$
\int_0^{90} f(x)\,dx = 
\int_0^{90} \left({1\over900}x^3 -{1\over5}x^2 +9x \right) dx=6075.
$$
Then the area of each of the two new paddocks is $6075/2 = 3037.5$.

We do not know the exact location of point $B$; we will now find it from the condition that the fence $AB$ cuts the field in half. The fence is a straight line that goes through $A(0,0)$, therefore the equation of the fence line is
$$
y= kx,
$$
where $k$ is unknown. The $x$-coordinate of $B(x_B,f(x_B))$ is connected with $k$ by the equation
$$
f(x) = kx,
$$
$$
{1\over900}x^3 -{1\over5}x^2 +9x = kx.
$$
Solving this equation we find $x=0$ or $x=90\pm30\sqrt{k}$. From the given picture we know that $x_B$ must be positive and less than $90$, hence
$$
x_B = 90 - 30\sqrt{k}.
$$

The area of the "upper-left" paddock bounded by the river and the fence is
$$
\int_0^{x_B} (f(x)-kx) dx = 3037.5,
$$
$$
{1\over3600}x_B^4 - {1\over15}x_B^3 + {9-k\over2}x_B^2 = 3037.5.
$$
Solving this together with $x_B = 90 - 30\sqrt{k}$, we find 
$$
k\approx 1.33907, \quad x_B = 90 - 30\sqrt{k} \approx 55.2845, 
\quad y_B = k \cdot x_B \approx 74.0299,
$$
and the length $L$ of the fence $AB$ is
$$
L=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2} \approx 92.4\,{\rm m}.
$$

**... and here is part (a)**

Approximating parabola can be chosen in many different ways. 
We'll use the following equation for our parabola:
$$
g(x) = px^2 + qx + r.
$$
Let's choose a parabola that passes through the points $A(0,0)$, $C(30,120)$, and $D(60,60)$. Then $r=0$, while for $p$ and $q$ we have the equations
$$
p \cdot 30^2 + q \cdot 30 = 120, \\
p \cdot 60^2 + q \cdot 60 = 60.
$$
Solving these equations we find $p = -{1\over10}, \ q = 7.$
So our parabola is 
$$
g(x) = -{1\over10}x^2 + 7x.
$$
Unlike the real (cubic) river, our parabola intersects the road ($x$-axis) at the points $(0,0)$ and $(70,0)$ - and not at $(90,0)$.

The approximate total area of two paddocks (the area bounded by the parabola and the road) is 
$$
\int_0^{70} g(x)\,dx = {17150\over3} \approx 5716.67.
$$
The fence line equation is $y=kx$, and the $x$ coordinate of $B$ is connected to 
$k$ by 
$$
g(x)=kx, \qquad
- {1\over10} x^2 + 7x = kx;
$$
solving this equation we find
$$
x_B = 70-10k.
$$

The area of the "upper-left" paddock bounded by the parabola and the fence is
then one-half of the whole field, i.e.
${17150\over6} = 2858\textstyle{1\over3},$
so we have this equation for the area of "upper-left" paddock:
$$
\int_0^{x_B} (g(x)-kx) dx = {17150\over6},
$$
$$
-{1\over30}x_B^3 + {7-k\over2} x_B^2 = {17150\over6}.
$$
Solving this together with $x_B = 70-10k$, we find
$$
k \approx 1.4441, \quad
x_B \approx 55.559, \quad
y_B = k\cdot x_B \approx 80.233,
$$
and the length $L$ of the fence $AB$ is
$$
L=\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A)^2} \approx 97.6\,{\rm m}.
$$

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thanks so much, Alex

Comment: Added part (a).

Comment: Sorry I'm so dumb I forgot to mention that both paddocks are of equal area if you cut from point A to B, so would that mean that the area would just be 5716.67 / 2?

Comment: Yes, each of the two paddocks is 2858.33 in part (a) *if our parabola goes through* (0,0), (30,120), (60,60). If we choose a different parabola, the area will also change. In part (b) each paddock is 6075/2 = 3037.5 square meters; I updated the solution accordingly. Also, point $B$ is no longer $(60,60)$.

Comment: I'm just wondering, in part B why is there xb = 90 - 30sqrt(k)?

Comment: To find $x_B$ (the $x$ coordinate of $B$), we solved the equation $$f(x)={1\over900}x^3 -{1\over5}x^2 +9x = kx.$$ This equation has three solutions: $x=0$, $x=90-30\sqrt{k}$ and $x=90+30\sqrt{k}$. But from the picture we know that $0<x_B<90$, so only one solution fits: $$x_B=90-30\sqrt{k}.$$

Comment: If you cannot solve this equation by hand, here's [a WolframAlpha command that solves it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1%2F900x%5E3-1%2F5x%5E2%2B9x%3Dkx).